# Python print first 3 items in counter

Tags: python, counter

Below is my counter, how do I only print the first 3

```
Counter({'Pittsburgh': 494.51, 'Austin': 380.6, 'Fort Worth': 368.45,
         'New York': 297.8, 'Stockton': 248.18, 'Omaha': 236.63,
         'San Jose': 215.05, 'San Diego': 67.08, 'Corpus Christi': 26.38})
```

I have tried doing that however it becomes an error

```
print(Counter[0,1,2])
```

I just want to print

```
{'Pittsburgh': 494.51, 'Austin': 380.6, 'Fort Worth': 368.45}
```

Comment: Define 'first 3'; a `Counter` is a dictionary, and dictionaries have no ordering.

Comment: I just want to print {'Pittsburgh': 494.51, 'Austin': 380.6, 'Fort Worth': 368.45}
@MartijnPieters

Comment: you want `.most_common()` ?

Comment: Ohh i actually am able to print it out now using the above method. Thx alot for the help

Answer (score 4):

A `Counter()` representation shows the contents in *sorted order* from most to least common (so highest to lowest count). Use the [`Counter.most_common()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) to get the top N key-value pairs in the same ordering:

```
counts = Counter({'Pittsburgh': 494.51, 'Austin': 380.6, 'Fort Worth': 368.45, 'New York': 297.8, 'Stockton': 248.18, 'Omaha': 236.63, 'San Jose': 215.05, 'San Diego': 67.08, 'Corpus Christi': 26.38})
for city, count in counts.most_common(3):
    print(city, count, sep=': ')
```

If you wanted a regular dictionary with just those top N elements, pass the output of `Counter.most_common()` to `dict()`:

```
print(dict(counts.most_common(3)))
```

Just take into account that prior to Python 3.6, dictionaries do not retain order and so the exact output order may differ, but it will contain the top 3 results.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter({'Pittsburgh': 494.51, 'Austin': 380.6, 'Fort Worth': 368.45, 'New York': 297.8, 'Stockton': 248.18, 'Omaha': 236.63, 'San Jose': 215.05, 'San Diego': 67.08, 'Corpus Christi': 26.38})
>>> for city, count in counts.most_common(3):
...     print(city, count, sep=': ')
...
Pittsburgh: 494.51
Austin: 380.6
Fort Worth: 368.45
>>> print(dict(counts.most_common(3)))
{'Pittsburgh': 494.51, 'Austin': 380.6, 'Fort Worth': 368.45}
```

The `Counter.__repr__` representation method uses the same `Counter.most_common()` method to produce the output order you see.

Comment: Wait, *confused*, so is `Counter()` ordered or not? Are you saying it's not but `print`/`repr` actually does the sorting but calling `.most_common()` under the hood?

Comment: Great answer. Just out of curiosity, how would you rate the performance of your `most_common()` solution vs something like `sorted(counts.items(), key = itemgetter(1), reverse = True)[:3]`? Does `most_common()` do basically the same thing under the hood? I apologize if this is a silly question.

Comment: @Chris_Rands: it is unordered, when you iterate over a counter it produces keys in hash table order.

Comment: @Chris_Rands: since `__repr__` is seen as *debugging support*, the cost for calling `.most_common()` is seen as worth it because it makes the output a little more helpful, given that you usually use counters to surface that information.

Comment: @RoadRunner: `most_common()` uses a heap queue to produce the order when N < K (length of the counter), which is O(KlogN) solution. Sorting is O(NlogN). So yes, sorting would be *slower* here, because you are doing way more work than is needed (you don't need to order all K elements, only the top N).